# Xvfb is already installed but throws error while using pyvirtualdisplay and suggests to install Xvfb

Tags: python, linux, selenium, flask, xvfb

I have been trying to run a selenium Chrome browser using pyvirtualdisplay inside a flask application as API on startup.

This is the code I'm trying to run

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pymongo.errors
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
browser = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", chrome_options=chromeOptions)

application = Flask(__name__)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
    browser.close()
    display.stop()
```

It is working fine when trying to run as

```
python project.py
```

But when deployed using uswgi and Nginx and while trying to start it throws the error

> File "./wsgi.py", line 1, in 
>       from project import application   File "./project.py", line 7, in 
>       display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))   File "/home/ubuntu/project/projectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py",
>   line 34, in **init**
>       self._obj = self.display_class(   File "/home/ubuntu/project/projectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py",
>   line 52, in display_class
>       cls.check_installed()   File "/home/ubuntu/project/projectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/xvfb.py",
>   line 38, in check_installed
>       ubuntu_package=PACKAGE).check_installed()   File "/home/ubuntu/project/projectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easyprocess/**init**.py",
>   line 180, in check_installed
>       raise EasyProcessCheckInstalledError(self) easyprocess.EasyProcessCheckInstalledError: cmd=['Xvfb', '-help']
>   OSError=[Errno 2] No such file or directory Program install error! 
>   You can install it in terminal: sudo apt-get install xvfb
>
> unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import
>   error)

Thanks

Comment: what do you get when running `Xvfb -help`?

Comment: it's working, I get all the commands available in Xvfb

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: No, I couldn't fix the issue with Xvfb instead, I changed the browser from Chrome to PhantomJS which is a headless browser and doesn't require display buffer.